# Composer + Laravel 4.2 - Unable to generate PSR-0 autoloader

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, autoload

**What i'm trying to do :** setup PSR-0 autoloading but composer is generating a PSR-4 autoloader file.

**I'm Using:**

1) Laravel 4.2

2) Composer version e77435cd0c984e2031d915a6b42648e7b284dd5c 2014-07-02 15:44:54

**My composer.json:**

```
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/libraries"
        ],
        "files": [
        "app/libraries/custom_helpers.php"
        ],
        "psr-0":{
            "MyApp":"app/"
        }
    }

//rest of the file is omitted
```

After this if i run `composer dump-autoload` in the terminal it should generate a file in the

**vendor/composer** directory called **autoload_psr0.php**

Instead it generates a autolooad_psr4.php and it looks like this :

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Monolog\\' => array($vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog'),
);
```

From the composer docs i understand that psr-0 is still supported.

Could this be due to to the Monolog package requiring PSR-4 namespacing ?

Comment: Your namespace MyApp has to be specified with two slashes at the end according to the [composer psr-0 documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0). I am not sure if this is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It doesn't seem to be the error though.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems laravel actually doesn't create a separate config for the psr0 standards. 
It in fact has a autoload_real.php file by default which references a ClassLoader class and checks for psr-0.
These files can be found in the vendor/composer directory.